Strapi fields are not fetched by GraphQL / Gatsby
The fields that are available in Strapi don't appear in GraphQL schema (GraphiQL playground)

I tried everything:

all permissions are given in the Roles;
deep population works, gatsby-source-strapi is configured (except for dynamic zones (for my sections' components) that I haven't even seen how to populate;
reconnecting my CMS to another (it's not even reconnected to another app - I see a starter GraphQL schema all the time);
Installed deep-populate Strapi plugin;
Anybody faced such a problem ???
P.S. I have a self-hosted Strapi CMS.


This gatsby-source-strapi plugin only take 2 level not take multi level. so we need to mention in the gatsby-config.js gatsby-source-strapi plugin config like below.
        {
        singularName: 'partner',
        queryParams: {
          populate: {
            'list': {
              populate: {                   
                'image':{
                  populate: "*"
                },
              }
            }
     }

I think this will help you.

Here's how I solved a situation in my gatsby-config:
{
            singularName: "page",
            queryParams: {
              populate: {
                sections: {
                  populate: [
                    "list.image",
                    "list.page",
                    "list.thumbnail",
                    "cta",
                    "images",
                    "image",
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
          },` 

